# customiser settings for checkbox (displaying content)

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm currently making a option in customiser to hide content using a checkbox, tick to show and unticked to hide.. was using it to apply the display:block and display:none on a id to get the effect but this doesnt seem to work properly.
ive been over the codex but cant seem to find a answer. is there a way to assign values to the checkbox? below is my code:
so by default the box should be ticked and showing the content. when unticked it should switch to display:none

```
    // WooCommerce Setting (toggle display - products on homepage)
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'woocommerce_productdisplay' , array(
'default'     => 'block',
'transport'   => 'refresh',
'sanitize_callback' => '',
) );

// WooCommerce Control (toggle display - products on homepage)
$wp_customize->add_control(
new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'woocommerce_productdisplay', array(
'label'     => __( 'Display Products on Page', 'woocommerce_productdisplay'),
'section'   => 'woocommerce_section',
'type'      => 'checkbox',

'settings'  => 'woocommerce_productdisplay',
) ) );

// ================================================================================== //

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'woocommerce_customize_register' );

function woocommerce_customize_css() {
?>
    <style>
        #woocommerce-container {display: <?php echo get_theme_mod('woocommerce_productdisplay', '');  ?>; }
    </style>
<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'woocommerce_customize_css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing some things from the settings array, namely `type` need to be `theme_mod` here and `capability` should be set too. You can try:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'woocommerce_productdisplay' , array(
'type'        => 'theme_mod',
'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
'default'     => '1',
'transport'   => 'refresh',
'sanitize_callback' => '',
) );
```

Also note `default` for a checkbox should be '1' for ticked. Then you would use slightly different code for the output also with this in mind:

```
<style>
#woocommerce-container {display: <?php 
    $display = get_theme_mod('woocommerce_productdisplay', '1');
    if ($display) {echo 'block';} else {echo 'none';}
?>; }
</style>
```